# Convert Eastern Time to local time from cli

Tags: bash, date, timezone

I'm trying to Convert [Eastern Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Time_Zone) to local time from CLI using the GNU date command.

I tried this :

```bash
$ remoteTime="8:03pm ET"
$ date -d "$remoteTime"
date: invalid date ‘8:03 pm ET’
```

but it does not work because the GNU `date` command expects `EST` or `EDT`.

How can I modify my `remoteTime` bash variable so that it automatically replaces `ET` by `EST` (autumn/winter) or `EDT` (spring/summer) depending on the current season ?

EDIT0 : I just found this [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones#List),
therefore an answer could be :

```bash
$ remoteTime="8:03pm ET"
$ remoteTZ=$(TZ=US/Eastern date '+%Z')
$ remoteTime=${remoteTime/ ET/ $remoteTZ}
$ date -d "$remoteTime"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `date` to report the current time zone with `%Z`, you just need to set the `$TZ` variable to a time zone where it's observed.

```
#!/bin/bash
remote_time='8:03pm ET'
zone=$(TZ=America/New_York date '+%Z')
remote_time=${remote_time%ET}$zone  # Remove ET from the end of remote time.
date -d "$remote_time"
```

Comment: This isn't a safe approach for all time zones.  For example, `TZ=Asia/Shanghai date '+%Z'` will give `CST`, which would subsequently be interpreted as US Central Standard Time by the second call to `date`.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint: The question was about converting ET to EST or EDT, not CST. Also, I used New York, not Shanghai. I don't get your point. The safe approach is to use the long timezone names, of course.

Comment: @choroba Just what I needed, thanks :+1:

Comment: Yes, it will work specifically for ET, as interpreted by `America/New_York`.  As long as it is only being use for that time zone.   It's just not a good general solution to the problem to be used on other time zones.

Answer (score 1):

GNU Date will accept an [IANA time zone identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) directly in the string passed to `-d` (or `--date`).  Use `America/New_York` for US Eastern Time.  It will properly use EST or EDT depending on which is in effect.

```
date -d 'TZ="America/New_York" 8:03pm'
```

That will convert from US Eastern Time to the *system's local time zone*, as you requested.  If instead you want to convert to a *specific* time zone, you can set the `TZ` environment variable.  For example, this converts from Eastern Time to Pacific Time:

```
TZ=America/Los_Angeles date -d 'TZ="America/New_York" 8:03pm'
```

More examples are [in the docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Examples-of-date.html).

Note that this only works with GNU date, such as on Linux.  The `date` command on MacOS does not support the `-d`/`--date` option.

Comment: Hi, you can install GNU date on MacOS with this command [`brew install coreutils`](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/coreutils) from [HomeBrew](https://brew.sh).